# Wie bezeichnet man die Strategie, mit einem günstigen Angebot Kunden zu ködern?

Tags: single-word-request

*Beispiel:*

> Software ist für Studenten oft gratis oder sehr stark verbilligt. Die Studenten gewöhnen sich an das Produkt und können dann damit gut umgehen.
>   Nach dem Studium kommt dann die Ernüchterung, da der Preis (z.B. für MatLab, MS Office) sehr hoch ist.

Oder:

> Der günstige Rasierer, dessen Klingen dann sehr teuer sind.

Wie nennt man diese (Marketing)strategie? Ist *Lockangebot* dafür geeignet?

- [wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Lockangebot) beschreibt das nicht notwendigerweise mit dem langfristigen Effekt, für den ich mich interessiere
- Lock(vogel)angebot/Loss leader (siehe [leo](http://dict.leo.org/#/search=lockangebot&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on)) ist laut der [Beschreibung](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockvogelangebot) auf Wikipedia etwas anderes

Falls zur Hand, würde ich mich auch über die englische Übersetzung freuen.

Comment: Gerade bei den Programmen für Studenten verstehe ich die negative Bewertung nicht - wenn der Student nach dem Studium im Wissenschaftsbetrieb bleibt, kenne ich es so, dass die Software von der Uni gestellt wird. Wenn er nach dem Studium den Wissenschaftsbetrieb verlässt, braucht er die Programme nicht mehr.

Comment: @Chris: ad _"braucht er die Programme nicht mehr"_ _Office?_ Echt?

Comment: Ich würde sogar sagen, dass gerade ein (ehem.) Student Office nicht braucht, weil er bessere Alternativen kennt. - Ist aber jetzt eine zu weit reichende Diskussion. ;-)

Comment: @Chris: Die aber in vielen Firmen leider(!) noch nicht flächendeckend eingesetzt werden. (Etwa aufgrund des „Anfütterns“? :-) [Matlab](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matlab) is kommerziell eingesetzte SW. Aber Du hast recht: ist schon etwas off-topic. Ich konnte das aber nicht so stehen lassen. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zunächst: es geht hier im Kern um Preisgestaltung. Laut Wikipedia ist [Preispolitik eine Teildisziplin des Marketing](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marketing-Mix#Preispolitik_.28Price.29); insofern könnte man durchaus von einer Marketing-Strategie sprechen. Ein anderer Aspekt wäre die Betrachtung als [Geschäftsmodell](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gesch%C3%A4ftsmodell), wofür es aber keine allgemein akzeptierte Definition gibt.

In beiden angeführten Situationen, insbesondere aber in der zweiten, geht es um das Erzielen eines [Lock-in-Effekts](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock-in-Effekt), bei Wikipedia auch *Anbindeeffekt* genannt. Verbilligte oder kostenlose Studentensoftware soll durch Gewöhnung und Übung sowie das Entstehen eines Archivs an Dokumenten in den anbieter-spezifischen Formaten den späteren Wechsel zu einem anderen Anbieter unattraktiv werden lassen. Der Käufer eines Naßrasierers ist an die Klingen desselben Anbieters gebunden.

Sowohl die [deutsche](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freemium) als auch die [englische](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freemium) Wikipedia führen kostenlose bzw. stark verbilligte Software für Studenten als Beispiel für ein **Freemium** genanntes Geschäftsmodell bzw. Preispolitik. Die kostenlose Variante des Produktes ist hierbei nicht, wie in vielen anderen Fällen, mit funktionalen Einschränkungen verbunden, sondern an die Zugehörigkeit des Kunden zu einer bestimmten Gruppe. Neben dem schon erwähnten Lock-in-Effekt kommen hier auch Werbung (Zielgruppe, die in Zukunft mit hoher Wahrscheinlichkeit als Kunde für das hochpreisige Produkt in Frage kommt) als auch [Preisdifferenzierung nach Kundensegmenten](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preisdifferenzierung#Preisdifferenzierung_3._Ordnung:_Segmentierung) als Motivation in Betracht.

Im Fall der Kombination von Naßrasiern und Klingen (oder auch Tintenstrahldruckern und Klingen, oder früher Polaroid-Kameras und Filmen) geht es um zwei miteinander in Beziehung stehende Produkte, von denen eines subventioniert wird, um mit dem anderen umso höhere Gewinne erwitschaften zu können. Im englischen Sprachraum sind dafür die Begriffe [**Freebie marketing**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freebie_marketing), [bait and hook business model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_model#History), "razor and blades business model" oder "tied products business model" üblich. Deutsche Begriffe dafür scheinen nicht etabliert zu sein. Die Übersetzung "Kopplungsproduktmodell" hat offenbar nahezu ausschließlich Wörterbuchseiten als Google-Treffer.

Comment: Knackpunkt beim Lock-in sind ja die hohen Wechselkosten, die auftreten, wenn man ein Produkt eines bestimmten Herstellers schon hat, aber wechseln möchte. Die Frage zielt aber eher auf die „(Marketing)strategie“ ab, die dies zu erreichen sucht.

Comment: Freebie-marketing trifft's auch nicht, weil das _"in order to increase sales of a **complementary** good"_ verwendet wird.

Comment: _bait and hook_ ist _"offering a basic product at a very low cost, [...]  then charging compensatory recurring amounts for **refills or associated products or services**"_ - ist's also auch eher nicht. Trotzdem +1 für die interessanten Links. ;-)

Comment: @GeriBroser Naßrasierer und Klingen werden in der Frage ausdrücklich angesprochen und sind geradezu das klassische Beispiel für freebie marketing bzw. bait and hook. Passen auch zu Deinen Zitaten. Wo siehst Du da ein Problem? - Da es im Kern um Preisgestaltung geht, würde ich eigentlich nicht von Marketing sprechen. Aber wenn man die Strategie begrifflich vom angestrebten Effekt trennen will, würde ich _Subventionierung von Kunden- oder Produktsegmenten_ vorschlagen.

Comment: Problem sehe ich hier überhaupt keines. (Täte ich das, hätte ich ein ganz anderes. :-) Für mich passten die Definitionen in WP einfach nur nicht ganz mit der Frage zusammen. Hier die „(Marketing)strategie“ _bevor_ noch ein Produkt überhaupt an irgend jemanden geht. Dort ein Zustand der nach erfolgtem Kauf besteht (Lock-in) und zwei Mal etwas wo es um _zusätzliche_ Produkte (oder Dienstleistungen) geht.

Comment: @GeriBroser  Wie gesagt, der Fall der _zusätzlichen_ Produkte steckt schon in der Frage mit drin. Zu den anderen Aspekten habe ich meine Antwort noch ergänzt.

Comment: Ja, Du hast recht. Das war wohl meinem Beruf, auch eins meiner Hobbys, geschuldet: Ich konzentrierte mich zu sehr auf die Software. +1 hast Du von mir aber ohnehin schon längst bekommen. :-)

Comment: @GeriBroser Es erscheint mir legitim die Strategie nach dem Effekt zu benennen der eingesetzt oder angestrebt wird. +1 für Lock-In

Comment: @Matthias, danke fuer Deine Antwort, die mir am besten gefallen hat. Ich finde, das trifft es sehr gut. Danke.

Answer (score 2):

Ich persönlich würde das Wort nehmen, das du bereits in der Überschrift verwendet hast: "Köder" oder "ködern". z.B.: "Kunden werden durch besonders attraktive Angebote geködert.". Etwas besseres ist denke ich schwer zu finden. Das englische Wort dafür wäre bait.

Ansonsten würde ich Wörter wie Lockmittel oder vllt. auch Blickfang benutzen.

Lockangebot versteht aber denke ich auch jeder.
GGf. kannst du es auch einfach mit "Verwöhnung mit anschließender Ausnutzung" bezeichnen, so, wie ich das verstanden habe.

Eine Bezeichnung für diese spezielle Strategie gibt es meines Wissens nicht.
Nimm stattdessen einfach eine Wortkombination, wie z.B. "Diese Strategie des Köderns..." oder "Diese Verwöhnungsstrategie mit anschließender Ausnutzung..."

Comment: Ich denke, die Übersetzung von Geri trifft es ganz gut. Sie ist ähnlich zum "Verwöhnen", hat aber noch den gewollten negativen Aspekt.

Answer (score 2):

Etwas pejorativ kann man "anfixen" verwenden - fixen ist ein pejoratives Verb für Heroinkonsum, und anfixen bedeutet, dass man jemanden von Heroin abhängig macht. Es wird gerne auch im Zusammenhang mit genau solchen Marketingstrategien verwendet.

Comment: Das ist nicht nur pejorativ, sondern auch umgangssprachlich.

Answer (score 2):

Ich denke, entweder ist das "ein günstiges Produkt mit hohen Folgekosten" oder es handelt sich um ein "Lockangebot". Auch bei Letzterem sehe ich den Zusatz "mit hohen Folgekosten" als angebracht an.

Answer (score 0):

Ich würde das, in übertragenem Sinn, als [Anfüttern](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=anf%C3%BCttern) bezeichnen. Auch wenn, beispielsweise [in Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anf%C3%BCttern), diese Variante (noch?) nicht genannt wird.

Ob das englische [Groundbaiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groundbait) in ähnlichem Sinn verwendet werden kann, kann ich nicht sagen. Ich fische nicht. Eine Anfrage an native speakers ist aber schon gestellt.

Folgende Konversation ergab sich daraus:

> Me: *An example: SW is sold to students at a low price or given to them for free. They become used to. After leaving university they realize that the real price they have to pay then is high.*
>
> *Can this be called "Groundbaiting"? In a figurative sense.*
>
> Friend: *Yes you could call it that, but I have never heard the term used outside of fishing.*
>
> Me: *We use the German counterpart for politicians that are tried to be corrupted by lobbyists, for instance. Giving them gifts, free trips, etc. without asking for anything in response at first. From a legal POV this is not bribery (yet).*
>
> Friend: *I haven't heard it used in english. But it does make complete sense to me. I may even start using it now. ;)*

Es scheint, als ob ich gerade einen neuen Begriff in die englische Sprache eingeführt hätte. ;-))

PS: Oder auch nicht: [Oxford English Dictionary, *ground-baiting*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/81812?redirectedFrom=groundbaiting#eid2553172) [Diese Seite speichert Cookies die verhindern, dass sie wiederholt aufgerufen werden kann. Cookies für *oed.com* im Browser löschen schafft Abhilfe.]:

*"1896 A. Morrison Child of Jago 236   A large swindle, requiring much ground-baiting and preliminary out~lay."*

> Me: If i interpret this correctly (with "swindle") and ignoring the typo or OCR flaw this goes into the fraud direction, doesn't it?
>
> Friend: yes... more fraud than bribery.. I think it's referring to setting up the scene for a fraud (I guess an equally valid use of the metaphor)